# No User Interface pops up when I create a nib file for my Tab Bar Controller

Tags: objective-c, xib, xcode4.3

I am creating a Tab Bar Controller xib file that will house the tab bar controller.  So I am highlighting my project folder for this and then creating a new file and then selecting the "Empty Template" from the i0S section on the left.  But once it is created I am not seeing the User Interface that should populate when you create the NIB file.  Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong possibly?  When creating other XIB(NIB) files I haven't encountered this but then I again I have never used an "Empty" template for it before either.

[image: No User Interface shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unlike other view controllers (e.g. UITableViewController) you should
>   not subclass the UITabViewController. Therefore, unlike other view
>   controllers, you don't subclass and then make your subclass the owner
>   of the nib, pointing at the view in the nib, with a customised view.

See this full [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448709/454165) for more info of what to do it instead.